# How to Use validation inside the service

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3.x

I would like to use validation inside the service.

**services.yml:**

```
AppBundle\Service\BookingCreateService:
            arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" , "@service_container"]
            public: true
```

**Status Entity:**

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="Status", type="string", length=35)
 * @Assert\Length(min="30", minMessage="error")
 */
private $status;
```

**BookingCreateService:**

```
class BookingCreateService
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $a= new Status();
        $a->setStatus("222");
            $this->em->persist($a);
        $this->em->flush();

    }
}
```

I would like the message about not meeting the validation conditions to be sent from the service to the controller. And then to the twig template.
I have read the documentation, but I do not know how to go about it :(

Comment: What is the wanted result? What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and {How much research effort is expected}(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: I would like the message about not meeting the validation conditions to be sent from the service to the controller. And then to the twig template.

Answer (score 1):

I've done it for now, but it can definitely be done better

```
public function create()
    {

        $errors = $this->validator->validate($a);

        if (count($errors) > 0) {

            $errorsString = (object) $errors;

            return $errorsString;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're wrong. Indeed, you do not need to call the validator in your service. This one is called automatically when you try to persist your entity. Just follow the symfony doc to [Create a custom Validation Constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/validation/custom_constraint.html)